# How to properly deploy a webapp to openshift?

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, openshift

I followed the instructions on https://www.openshift.com/blogs/day-28-openshift-eclipse-integration-for-java-developers

Anyhow, when opening my app, I'm getting `503 Service Unavailable`.

How can I verify that the build was actually successful on `openshift`?

This is the output during publishing:

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.4:war (default-war) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [my-app] in [/var/lib/openshift/5369ed42e0b8cdc66a00027c/app-root/runtime/repo/target/my-app]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [6408 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /var/lib/openshift/5369ed42e0b8cdc66a00027c/app-root/runtime/repo/deployments/ROOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.1.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ my-app ---
```

Ony my local machine and a local build, thereafter would be a build successful message like:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.385s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed May 07 11:15:48 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/32M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But this is missing then publishing to openshift. Is this telling me the build was not successful in the cloud?

Comment: You should check your log files for specific error messages.  Also, the above does not look like the complete logs as no error is shown, only INFO.

Comment: OK I did not know I can request the tail logs from their servers via the plugin. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly deploy a war openshift, don't need to build it on the server, for reference:
https://www.openshift.com/kb/kb-e1088-how-to-deploy-pre-compiled-java-applications-war-and-ear-files-onto-your-openshift-gear